# VSCode Java Debugger throwing unknown error

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

I had to re-install VSCode on my machine after an issue I was having, and after having done so, I can no longer run my Spring application. There is no error code, thrown, I can't find it in the VSCode logs, and the dialog isn't even copyable.

This is the error dialog displayed: [image: Error Dialog]

```
'void
org.eclipse.jdi.internal.connect.ConnectorImpl$StringArgumentImpl.<init>(org.eclipse.jdi.i...
java.lang.String,java.lang.String, java.lang.String, boolean)'
```

The launch.json configuration was auto-generated by Spring Initializr, and previously worked. No changes have been made to my JDK or my pom.xml.

I also created a new test app and it had the same problem, so it's not limited to this app or workspace.

Any ideas of what is going on here? (I tried googling the... error... but got not anything helpful)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going to go ahead and answer this, as I've fixed it.

I had the latest versions of both VSCode and the Java Debugger extension (I had just re-installed them both).

I wound up re-installing Windows entirely (spring cleaning), and now it's working again.

Answer (score 3):

You need update "Debugger for Java" extension to 0.33.1, which has fixed it.

See https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-java-debug/issues/995

Update: "Debugger for Java" 0.33.1 also requires your VS Code version to be 1.55.0 and above.

Answer (score 1):

This error occurs when we don't have the latest version of 'debugger for java' extension. We have to update the version to v0.33.1. In order to update to the latest version of extension you need to have the latest version of VSCode(1.55.0).

You can get the latest version of VSCode from here : https://code.visualstudio.com/

Download the .deb package and then open the file directory in terminal. Use 'dpkg -i filename.deb' command to install the latest version. Restart the VSCode and update the extension.

Note, that after updating VSCode, the extensions might need updating and another restart of VSCode before both VSCode and extensions are running latest versions.